# How to set navigation bar toggle when collapsible toolbar is collapsed?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, toolbar, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

It works great when the collapsible toolbar is expanded but when I scroll up to make it collapsed into just the toolbar, the toolbar only shows my app name. I want it to also show the hamburger toggle.

Code:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that your Toolbar hasn't been told to draw an icon to the left of the title at all. When your Toolbar is expanded, the CollapsingToolbarLayout is then telling the Toolbar to have the icon.

So, if you want your Toolbar to have an icon to the left of the title, you can do this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

You normally don't need to do this because the Activity will tell the ActionBar to show the icon already if the Activity has a parent Activity. Therefore I suspect in your case we're talking about your launcher activity.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I had set my toolbar within my collapsable toolbar to parallax when it should have been pinned.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />
```